# SQL Server - exclude data where there's no connection to second table

Tags: sql-server-2008

The example below shows the result for every `Name` that has a connection to Table2 (Table1 `TId` is PK, and `TId` in Table2 is the FK).

```
SELECT T1.Name, T1.Address
FROM Table1 AS T1
    INNER JOIN Table2 AS T2
    ON T1.TId = T2.TId;
```

I want a list of all Names from `Table1` that have NO corresponding row in `Table2`. The other way around so to speak. How could this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an `Outer Join` as shown below:

```
SELECT T1.Name, T1.Address
FROM Table1 AS T1
     LEFT OUTER JOIN Table2 AS T2 ON T1.TId = T2.TId
WHERE T2.TId IS NULL
```